# How to reset the background colour of all other buttons and highlight the selected button when clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to reset all the background colours when I click on one button and change the colour of the selected button. I want in the beginning for one button to have the background colour of dark grey as shown in the snippet, and when I click on another button all of the buttons would be resetted back to white and the clicked button will turn dark grey. How can I achieve this?

Right now when I click on another button nothing happens.

This is my code, what is wrong?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>

        /* Style the buttons */
        .portfolio-buttons {
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            padding: 12px 16px;
            /* background-color: white; */
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .portfolio-buttons-normal {
            background-color: white;
        }

        .portfolio-buttons:hover {
            background-color: #ddd;
        }

        .portfolio-buttons-active {
            background-color: #666;
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="myBtnContainer">
        <button class="portfolio-buttons portfolio-buttons-normal portfolio-buttons-active">Show
            all</button>
        <button class="portfolio-buttons portfolio-buttons-normal" >.html</button>
        <button class="portfolio-buttons portfolio-buttons-normal">.css</button>
        <button class="portfolio-buttons portfolio-buttons-normal" >.js</button>
        <button class="portfolio-buttons portfolio-buttons-normal" >.java</button>
        <button class="portfolio-buttons portfolio-buttons-normal" >.py</button>
    </div>
    <script>

        
        function changeClass(button, classRef) {

            button.classList.forEach((className) => {

                if (className.startsWith("portfolio-buttons-active")) button.classList.remove(className);

            });

            console.log(classRef);
            button[classRef].classList.add("portfolio-buttons-active");
        }


        document.querySelectorAll("portfolio-buttons").forEach((button, buttonNum) => {
            button.addEventListener("click", function () {
                document.querySelectorAll(".portfolio-buttons-normal").forEach((item) => {
                    changeClass(item, buttonNum);
                    console.log(buttonNum);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are over-complicating it :) You are setting up your click listener correctly, but you just need 2 simple steps inside the listener:

**1. Reset the current active button:** simply get all buttons with the *active* class (we don't care about the rest, so no need to process them!) and remove it:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".portfolio-buttons-active").forEach((button) => {
     button.classList.remove("portfolio-buttons-active");
});
```

**2. Set the clicked button to active:** your click handler is added to the button so we when that button is clicked button, add the active class to it:

```
    button.classList.add("portfolio-buttons-active");
```

**That's it! Putting this together** all you need is the following:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".portfolio-buttons").forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", function() {

    // Reset the currently active buttons:
    document.querySelectorAll(".portfolio-buttons-active").forEach((button) => {
        button.classList.remove("portfolio-buttons-active");
    });

    // Add the active class to the clicked button
    button.classList.add("portfolio-buttons-active");
  });
});
```

**Working Example:** I've put steps 1 and 2 into functions in this code, in case you need to add more functionality in each step later

```js
/* Add the active class to the button passed in */
function setThisButtonActive(button) {
  button.classList.add("portfolio-buttons-active");
}

/* select all active buttons, and remove the active class from them */
function resetActiveButton() {
  document.querySelectorAll(".portfolio-buttons-active").forEach((button) => {
    button.classList.remove("portfolio-buttons-active");
  });
}

document.querySelectorAll(".portfolio-buttons").forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    resetActiveButton();
    setThisButtonActive(button);
  });
});
```

```css
/* Style the buttons */

.portfolio-buttons {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  /* background-color: white; */
  cursor: pointer;
}

.portfolio-buttons-normal {
  background-color: white;
}

.portfolio-buttons:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.portfolio-buttons-active {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="myBtnContainer">
  <button class="portfolio-buttons portfolio-buttons-normal portfolio-buttons-active">Show
            all</button>
  <button class="portfolio-buttons portfolio-buttons-normal">.html</button>
  <button class="portfolio-buttons portfolio-buttons-normal">.css</button>
  <button class="portfolio-buttons portfolio-buttons-normal">.js</button>
  <button class="portfolio-buttons portfolio-buttons-normal">.java</button>
  <button class="portfolio-buttons portfolio-buttons-normal">.py</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `.` in the `querySelectorAll` where you select the buttons. So it's looking for the element `portfolio-buttons` instead of the class.

The `classList` interface has a [`contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/contains) method which checks if a class is present on an element. So there is no need to loop and check the `className` string. Also there is no need at all, if the class is not on the element nothing is removed.

For the reset button, give it a way to identify it's uniqueness. In the example above I gave it a `value` attribute with a string in it. When clicking check the if it is the reset button that is clicked and simply don't add a new active class.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".portfolio-buttons");
buttons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', event => {
    buttons.forEach(button => button.classList.remove('portfolio-buttons-active'));
    if (button.value !== 'reset') {
      button.classList.add('portfolio-buttons-active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/* Style the buttons */

.portfolio-buttons {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  /* background-color: white; */
  cursor: pointer;
}

.portfolio-buttons-normal {
  background-color: white;
}

.portfolio-buttons:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.portfolio-buttons-active {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="myBtnContainer">
  <button class="portfolio-buttons portfolio-buttons-normal portfolio-buttons-active" value="reset">Show all</button>
  <button class="portfolio-buttons portfolio-buttons-normal">.html</button>
  <button class="portfolio-buttons portfolio-buttons-normal">.css</button>
  <button class="portfolio-buttons portfolio-buttons-normal">.js</button>
  <button class="portfolio-buttons portfolio-buttons-normal">.java</button>
  <button class="portfolio-buttons portfolio-buttons-normal">.py</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify it by checking `e.target`:

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".portfolio-buttons");

buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.target.classList.add('portfolio-buttons-active');
    
    buttons.forEach(item => {
      if (item !== e.target) {
        item.classList.remove('portfolio-buttons-active');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.portfolio-buttons {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  /* background-color: white; */
  cursor: pointer;
}

.portfolio-buttons-normal {
  background-color: white;
}

.portfolio-buttons:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.portfolio-buttons-active {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="myBtnContainer">
  <button class="portfolio-buttons portfolio-buttons-normal portfolio-buttons-active">Show
            all</button>
  <button class="portfolio-buttons portfolio-buttons-normal">.html</button>
  <button class="portfolio-buttons portfolio-buttons-normal">.css</button>
  <button class="portfolio-buttons portfolio-buttons-normal">.js</button>
  <button class="portfolio-buttons portfolio-buttons-normal">.java</button>
  <button class="portfolio-buttons portfolio-buttons-normal">.py</button>
</div>
```

If `e.target` isn't the current element in the loop, then remove the active class, otherwise, add the active class.